# How do I aggregate hourly data to daily, weekly, monthly and yearly values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, average

I have a table `my_data` in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database containing hourly data. The sample data is like:

```
ID  Date        hour    value
1   01/01/2014  1       9.947484
2   01/01/2014  2       9.161652
3   01/01/2014  3       8.509986
4   01/01/2014  4       7.666654
5   01/01/2014  5       7.110822
6   01/01/2014  6       6.765822
7   01/01/2014  7       6.554989
8   01/01/2014  8       6.574156
9   01/01/2014  9       6.09499
10  01/01/2014  10      8.471653
11  01/01/2014  11      11.36581
12  01/01/2014  12      11.25081
13  01/01/2014  13      9.391651
14  01/01/2014  14      6.976655
15  01/01/2014  15      6.574156
16  01/01/2014  16      6.420823
17  01/01/2014  17      6.229156
18  01/01/2014  18      5.577491
19  01/01/2014  19      4.964159
20  01/01/2014  20      6.593323
21  01/01/2014  21      7.321654
22  01/01/2014  22      9.295818
23  01/01/2014  23      8.241653
24  01/01/2014  24      7.014989
25  02/01/2014  1       6.842489
26  02/01/2014  2       7.513321
27  02/01/2014  3       7.244988
28  02/01/2014  4       5.80749
29  02/01/2014  5       5.481658
30  02/01/2014  6       6.669989
..  ..          ..      ..
```

and so on. The data exist for many years in the same manner. Structure of above table is: ID (integer serial not null), Date (date) (mm/dd/yyyy), hour (integer), value (numeric). For a large set of data like above, how do I find daily, weekly, monthly and yearly averages in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use aggregation.  For instance:

```
select date, avg(value)
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

For the rest, use `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as yyyymm, avg(value)
from t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

This assumes that `date` is stored as a `date` data type.  If it is stored as a string you should fix the data type in your data.  You can convert it to a date using `to_date()`.

Comment: The first case worked fine but for the monthly average. It returedn dates like: 2014-01-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-04-01 instead of yyyymm as specified in the code? Date values are stored as date.

Comment: @JibranKhan . . . `date_trunc()` returns the first day of the month.  I just call it `yyyymm` to indicate that it represents a month.  `to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')` could also be used.